# Devise two user models password reset

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm using devise with two user models  - an Employee model and Employer Model.

I'm having issues trying to get the password reset link to work with both models. 
Currently devise wildly send the password reset link to the users that belong to the Employee model and will not find users the belong to the Employer model.

Any suggestions on how to configure devise to work with both Models.

The two models are:

```
class Employer < ActiveRecord::Base
 #Twilo
  ACCOUNT_SID = '#####'
  ACCOUNT_TOKEN = '####'


  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable,
  # :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :timeoutable, :lockable

  acts_as_token_authenticatable


  before_create :create_twilio_subaccount

  after_create :rent_number



  validates :first_name, :presence => {:message => 'Cannot be blank'}
  validates :last_name, :presence => {:message => 'Cannot be blank'}

  validates_acceptance_of :terms




  validates_format_of :first_name, :with => /\A[a-zA-Z ]*\z/i,
    :message => "can only contain letters and spaces."

  validates_format_of :last_name, :with => /\A[a-zA-Z ]*\z/i,
    :message => "can only contain letters and spaces."

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password, :remember_me, :first_name, :terms,
   :last_name, :tax_file_number, :phone_number, :address, :state_id, :post_code, :location, :avatar, :business, :latitude, :longitude, :paid_employees, :sms_phone_number

  attr_accessor :current_password

  # attr_accessible :title, :body
  has_one :setting, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :employees, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :message_threads, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :messages, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :schedules, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :tasks, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :announcements
  has_many :keychains
  has_one :quickbook


  mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader


  geocoded_by :full_address
  after_validation :geocode

  scope :recent_signups, where(:created_at => Date.today..28.days.from_now.to_date)


  class << self # Class methods
  end

  def full_address
    "#{address} #{post_code}"  
  end

  def get_full_name
    "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
  end


  private
  def create_twilio_subaccount
    @client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(ACCOUNT_SID, ACCOUNT_TOKEN)
    @subaccount = @client.accounts.create({:FriendlyName => self[:email]})

    self.twilio_account_sid = @subaccount.sid
    self.twilio_auth_token  = @subaccount.auth_token
  end



  def rent_number
    # create a new Twilio client for subaccount
    @sub_account_client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(self[:twilio_account_sid], self[:twilio_auth_token])
    @subaccount = @sub_account_client.account

    @numbers = @subaccount.available_phone_numbers.get('US').local.list({:area_code => '858'})


    # buy the first one
    @purchased_number = @subaccount.incoming_phone_numbers.create(:phone_number => @numbers[0].phone_number)

    phone_number = @purchased_number.phone_number

   self[:sms_phone_number] = @purchased_number


  end

end
```

and the second model is:

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  #  :omniauthable :registerable,
  devise :database_authenticatable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :timeoutable, :lockable

  acts_as_token_authenticatable



  validates :first_name, :presence => {:message => 'cannot be blank'}
  validates :last_name, :presence => {:message => 'cannot be blank'}
  validates :birthday, :presence => {:message => 'cannot be blank'}
  # validates :position, :presence => {:message => 'cannot be blank'}
  validates :base_rate, :presence => {:message => 'cannot be blank'}
  validates :employment_status, :presence => {:message => 'cannot be blank'}


  validates_format_of :first_name, :with => /\A[a-zA-Z ]*\z/i,
:message => "can only contain letters and spaces."

  validates_format_of :last_name, :with => /\A[a-zA-Z ]*\z/i,
:message => "can only contain letters and spaces."


  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :position, :password_confirmation, :current_password, :remember_me, :first_name, :last_name, :tax_file_number, 
                   :phone_number, :address, :state_id, :post_code, :avatar, :location, :employment_type, :hired_at, :birthday
  # attr_accessible :title, :body

  attr_accessor :current_password

  belongs_to :employer
  has_many :messages, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :schedules, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :keychains, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :announcements, through: :employer
  has_one :position
  has_many :employee_locations
  has_many :locations, :through => :employee_locations
  has_many :tasks

  mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader


  scope :expect, lambda { joins(:schedules).merge(Schedule.expected)}




  def get_full_name
    "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
  end

  def self.search(search)
    if search
      where("LOWER(first_name) LIKE ? OR LOWER(last_name) LIKE ? OR first_name LIKE ? OR last_name LIKE ?" , "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%")
    else
      scoped
    end
  end

  class << self # Class methods
    def get_by_employer(employer_id)
      self.where('employer_id = ?', employer_id).order('LOWER(last_name) ASC')
    end
  end
end
```

The error message just states:

Oh no! 1 error was detected preventing this employee from being saved:

Email not found

It's only looking at the employee model and not both.

Comment: Can you please provide your models and error message?

Comment: You have generated the devise stuff with User model. Employee and Employer should be a role of User so you will get the password reset link for all Users. Isn't it?

Comment: Devise was generated with the Employee and Employer not the standard User. They are separate models.